# How do I echo out a value from WP_term object?

Tags: php, wordpress

So All I want to do is to echo the 'name' value on an `<h1>` basically. So I am wanting to display the taxonomy name this current Post belongs to and I am able to get it by doing this:

```
   $term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'state');
```

So this particular post belongs to the Nebraska state so if I do a var dump on $term_obj_list i get this:

```
    var_dump($term_obj_list);
```

This is that it prints:

```
    array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(WP_Term)[3262]
      public 'term_id' => int 116
      public 'name' => string 'Nebraska' (length=8)
      public 'slug' => string 'nebraska' (length=8)
      public 'term_group' => int 0
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 116
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'state' (length=5)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => int 0
      public 'count' => int 9
      public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

So there it is `public 'name' => string 'Nebraska' (length=8)` How am I supposed to echo this to an html line?

I tried  `echo $term_obj_list-> name` but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, i tried getting rid of the space and also adding a space.  Still didn't work.

Comment: That's because you are returning an **array** of objects. You need to do a `foreach` on the array first, or pick what array key you want.

Answer (score 2):

Because it appears to return an *array* of objects, you would first need to specify the index in the array before attempting to read the object attributes.

Try:

```
echo $term_obj_list[0]-> name
```

Comment: Dang it, i see now. That worked thanks!

Comment: Would there by any other way to do this though? without having to pull an array of objects.

Comment: That might be worth a separate question, but given the function you mentioned, that is designed to return _multiple_ terms (because one post may have many terms, not just one term). Most often you'd use the list of terms with a loop.